# Why is my Python decorator class's __get__ method not called in all cases?

Tags: python, python-decorators

So I'm trying to implement something akin to C# events in Python as a decorator for methods:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import *
import functools


def event(function: Callable) -> EventDispatcher:
    return EventDispatcher(function)


class EventDispatcher:

    def __init__(self, function: Callable) -> None:
        functools.update_wrapper(self, function)

        self._instance: Any | None = None
        self._function: Callable = function
        self._callbacks: Set[Callable] = set()

    def __get__(self, instance: Any, _: Any) -> EventDispatcher:
        self._instance = instance
        return self

    def __iadd__(self, callback: Callable) -> EventDispatcher:
        self._callbacks.add(callback)
        return self

    def __isub__(self, callback: Callable) -> EventDispatcher:
        self._callbacks.remove(callback)
        return self

    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        for callback in self._callbacks:
            callback(*args, **kwargs)

        return self._function(self._instance, *args, **kwargs)
```

But when I decorate a class method with `@event` and later on call the decorated method, the method will be invoked on the incorrect instance in some cases.

**Good Case:**

```
class A:

    @event
    def my_event(self) -> None:
        print(self)


class B:

    def __init__(self, a: A) -> None:
        a.my_event += self.my_callback

    def my_callback(self) -> None:
        pass


a0 = A()
a1 = A()

# b = B(a0)

a1.my_event()
a0.my_event()
```

The above code will result in the output:

```
<__main__.A object at 0x00000170AA15FCA0>
<__main__.A object at 0x00000170AA15FC70>
```

Evidently the function `my_event()` is called twice, each time with a different instance as expected.

**Bad Case:**

Taking the code from the good case and commenting in the line `# b = B(a0)` results in the output:

```
<__main__.A object at 0x000002067650FCA0>
<__main__.A object at 0x000002067650FCA0>
```

Now the method `my_event()` is called twice, too. But on the same instance.

**Question:**

I think the issue boils down to `EventDispatcher.__get__()` not being called in the bad case. So my question is, why is `EventDispatcher.__get__()` not called and how do I fix my implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in the initializer of `B`:

```
a.my_event += self.my_callback
```

Note that the `+=` operator is not just a simple call to `__iadd__`, but actually equivalent to:

```
a.my_event = a.my_event.__iadd__(self.my_callback)
```

<sub>This is also the reason why your `__iadd__` method needs to return self.</sub>

Because the class `EventDispatcher` has only `__get__` but no `__set__`, the result will be written to the instance's attribute during assignment, so the above statement is equivalent to:

```
a.__dict__['my_event'] = A.__dict__['my_event'].__get__(a, A).__iadd__(self.my_callback)
```

Simple detection:

```
print(a0.__dict__)
b = B(a0)
print(a0.__dict__)
```

Output:

```
{}
{'my_event': <__main__.EventDispatcher object at 0x00000195218B3FD0>}
```

When `a0` calls `my_event` on the last line, it only takes the instance of `EventDispatcher` from `a0.__dict__` (instance attribute access takes precedence over non data descriptors, refer to [invoking descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors)), and does not trigger the `__get__` method. Therefore, `A.__dict__['my_event']._instance` will not be updated.

---

The simplest repair way is to add an empty `__set__` method to the definition of `EventDispatcher`:

```
class EventDispatcher:
    ...

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        pass

    ...
```

Output:

```
<__main__.A object at 0x000002A36B9B3D30>
<__main__.A object at 0x000002A36B9B3D00>
```

Comment: So the way Python resolves attributes causes it to not call `__get__` if it already finds the attribute in `instance.__dict__`? 

By defining an empty `__set__` (like you described) the default `__set__` which adds the `value` to `instance.__dict__` is overriden and the value essentially never gets added to `instance.__dict__`, hence python will always call `__get__` to resolve the attribute?

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tuntenfisch Your understanding is absolutely correct.